# awk to add specific fields to file based on match in field

Tags: awk

I am trying to use `awk` to add the `$4`,`$5`,`$6` fields and the header in the `tab-delimeted` `file2` to the lines that in `file2` `$2` there is a matching `$3` value in `file1`. I added comments to each line as well as to my understanding of whats going on. Thank you :).

**file1**  `tab-delimeted`

```
ID  Name    Number
0-0 A,A 123456
2-2 B,B 789123
4-4 C,C 456789
```

**file2**  `tab-delimeted`

```
ID  Number  Name    Info1   Info2   Info3   Info4
0-0 123456  A,A aaaaa   bbbbb   ccccc   eeeee
1-1 111111  Z,Z aaa bbb ccc eee
2-2 789123  B,B aaaaa   bb,bbb  ccccc   eeeee
3-3 222222  Y,Y aaa bb,bb   cc  e
4-4 456789  C,C aaa bb  ccc eeee
```

**desired output**  `tab-delimeted`

```
ID  Name    Number  Info1   Info2   Info3
0-0 A,A 123456  aaaaa   bbbbb   ccccc
2-2 B,B 789123  aaaaa   bb,bbb  ccccc
4-4 C,C 456789  aaa bb  ccc
```

**awk**

```
awk -F"\t" '$3 in a{  # read $3 value of file1 into array a
 a[$3]=a[$2];   # match $3 array a from file1 with $2 value in file2
  next   # process next line
 }  # close block
  { print $1,$2,a[$2],$4,$5,$6  # print desired output
 }  # close block
    END {  # start block
 for ( i in a) {   # create for loop i to print
     print a[i]  # print for each matching line in i
  }  # close block
}' file1 file2
```

Comment: Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins. You've had many similar questions answered here (and the archives contain hundreds more), so you shouldn't have had to ask this one unless you're missing something fundamental that you could get from that book.

Comment: I am reading that book, along with a couple others, and am learning but this is a bit out of my realm of expertise. I will keep reading and trying. Thank you everyone for the help, explanations, and patience :)... its a steep learning curve but one that is extremely valuable and needed in science. Thank you :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -v OFS="\t" 'NR==FNR{a[$3]=$0;next}$2 in a{print a[$2],$4,$5,$6}' file1 file2
ID      Name    Number  Info1   Info2   Info3
0-0     A,A     123456  aaaaa   bbbbb   ccccc
2-2     B,B     789123  aaaaa   bb,bbb  ccccc
4-4     C,C     456789  aaa     bb      ccc
```

Explained:

```
$ awk -v OFS="\t" '         # tab as OFS also
NR==FNR{                    # for file1
    a[$3]=$0                # hash $0 to a using $3 as key
    next                    # no further processing for this record
}
$2 in a {                   # if $2 found in a
    print a[$2],$4,$5,$6    # output as requested
}' file1 file2              # mind the file order
```

Answer (score 1):

try: one more approach reading file2 first and then reading file1.

```
awk -F"\t" 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$3,$2]=$4 OFS $5 OFS $6;next} (($1,$2,$3) in a){print $1,$2,$3,a[$1,$2,$3]}' OFS="\t" file2 file1
```

Will add explanation in few mins.

EDIT: Adding non-one liner form of solution along with the explanation too.

```
awk -F"\t" 'FNR==NR{                              ####Checking condition FNR==NR which will be only true when first file named file2 is being read. Because FNR and NR both represent the number of lines for a Input_file, only difference is FNR value will be RESET whenever it is starting to read next Input_file and NR value will be keep on increasing till all the Input_files are being read.
                a[$1,$3,$2]=$4 OFS $5 OFS $6;     ####Creating an array named a whose index is $1,$3 and $2 and value is $4,$5 and $6. Where OFS is output field separator, whose default value is space.
                next                              ####next is awk built-in keyword which will NOT allow cursor to go further and will skip all next statements.
            }
     (($1,$2,$3) in a){                           ####Checking a condition which will be only checked when 2nd Input_file is being read. So checking here if $1, $2 and $3 is present in array a, then do following.
                        print $1,$2,$3,a[$1,$2,$3]####print the value of $1, $2,$3 and array a value whose index is $1,$2 and $3.
                      }
    ' OFS="\t" file2 file1                        ####Mentioning the Input_files here.
```